# Hover effect only on particular class

Tags: html, css

***I have added the link of the image below. Please watch the left sidebar which contains 5 elements such as Offers Near You, TopPick and so on. Whenver user click on the Top Pick than only the image adjecent to Top Pick should hover and not the text "Top Picks".***

```
<div className="Offer__Sidebar">
  <div className="Offers_Near_You">
    <img className="Offer__img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/swiggy/image/upload/fl_lossy,f_auto,q_auto,w_90,h_90/hxizld3pqhnk0smw27sl" />
    <div className="Offer__div">
      <div>Offers Near You</div>
      <p>211 OPTIONS</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="Top_Picks">

  </div>
  <div className="Whats_New">

  </div>
  <div className="Vegeterian_Options">

  </div>
  <div className="See_All">

  </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmzwG.png)

Comment: It's not clear what exactly your problem is. Do you want a hover effect on a particular element? And what is your relevant CSS?

Comment: It is not very clear what the issue is, based on the information you have provided.

Comment: Whenever the user hover over a className "Offer_Near_You"(that is on any element of this class) than the hover effect should be applied to only img and not to any other element of  "Offer_Near_You".

Comment: I have added the link of the image below. Please watch the left sidebar which contains 5 elements such as Offers Near You, TopPick and so on. Whenver user click on the Top Pick than only the image adjecent to Top Pick should hover and not the text "Top Picks".

Answer (score 1):

You can select the img when the Offers_Near_You is hovered by:

```
.Offers_Near_You:hover img { put the styling you want for img here }
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working